# How do i make a condition that will end the program, and prevent further cout statements?

Tags: c++, terminal

I'm currently making a text-based game just for kicks, which gives the user three options to choose from. One of the options allows the user to continue, while the others end the game with a "GAME OVER" text. I thought that making an endGame() function would do the trick, but the terminal still outputs the rest of the cout statements. How can I make the endGame() function end the program? 
(The program isn't finished yet, I still plan on adding a lot of features. I just can't continue until I solve this.)

Also, is there a way I can confirm that the user inputs either 1, 2, or 3 for each question and return "Enter 1, 2 or 3!" for wrong answers, without having to code it into each question?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void endGame (void)
{
    cout << "GAME OVER\n";
}

int main() 
{
    string userName;
    //int choice1;
    //int choice2;
    //int choice3;
    int event1;
    int event2;
    int event3;
    int event4;
    int event5;

    cout << "What is your name, traveler?" << endl;
    cin >> userName;

    cout << "\nWelcome, " << userName << "." << endl;
    cout << "I'm going to ask you a series of questions." << endl;
    cout << "To cotinue your adventure, answer them by typing" << endl;
    cout << "either 1, 2, or 3." << endl;

    cout << "\nYou're walking down a long dirt road. You hear footsteps behind you," << endl;
    cout << "but you're too afraid to look right now. A fork in the road lies infront of you." << endl;

    cout << "\nWhat do you do?" << endl;
    cout << "1 - Turn left, and run down the hill." << endl;
    cout << "2 - Turn right, and run towards the abandoned house in the distance." << endl;
    cout << "3 - Gain the courage to turn around and face whatever is behind you." << endl;
    cin >> event1;
    if(event1 == 1)
    {
        cout << "Unfortunatley, you trip over a branch, and fall to your death.\n" << endl;
        endGame();
    }
    else if(event1 == 2)
    {
        cout << "You run towards the house, and escape the creature following you." << endl;
    }
    else if(event1 == 3)
    {
        cout << "You turn around, but before you can make out the features of the creature behind you, it kills you.\n" << endl;
        endGame();
    }   

    cout << "As you get closer to the house, you notice a light is on upstairs." << endl;
    cout << "A small path leads to the back of the house.\n" << endl;
    cout << "What do you do?" << endl;
    cout << "1 - Knock on the door, and hope whoever is inside won't kill you." << endl;
    cout << "2 - Enter the hoouse unanounced, and sneak upstairs." << endl;
    cout << "3 - Follow the path to the back of the house." << endl;
    cin >> event2;
    if(event2 == 1)
    {
        cout << "A drunk, confused man answers the door, shotgun in hand." << endl;
        cout << "You raise your hands in defense, but before you can explain yourself, he shoots." << endl;
        endGame();
    }
    else if(event2 == 2)
    {
        cout << "You slowly open the door, and quietly sneak upstairs." << endl;
    }
    else if(event2 == 3)
    {
        cout << "You sneak around the house, and become face to face with a vicious gaurd dog." << endl;
        cout << "Before you can give it a Scooby-Snac, it bits your throat, and kills you." << endl;
        endGame();
    }
    cout << "You see three doorways, one leads to a dimly lit room, the second to a brightly lit room, and the third to a pitch black room." << endl;
    cout << "\nWhat do you do?" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use an `if` statement. You seem to already know how to do that.

Comment: How would I use an `if` statement to end the program?

Comment: `exit()`? `abort()`?

Comment: Consider showing this to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) once it works as intended, Its not good to mix code and data. Consider putting the text in a file and a program that does the functionality. Use the `switch` statement instead of `if`-`else`-chains. You do not need different variables for the events. You do not check if you read the input correctly or the user put in a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use `switch` `case` for the conditions and a `while` loop for the enter 1,2,3 thing.. Something like

```
bool running=true;
while(running)
{ 
    running = false;
    switch(i)
    { 
        case 1: stuff; break;
        case 2: stuff; break;
        case 3: stuff; break;
        default: cout<<"enter 1,2,3"; running = true;
    }
}
```

For the endgame thing make the endgame function lime this

```
void endgame()
{
    cout<<"game over";
    system("PAUSE");
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Also since I'm a grammar nazi. You misspelled house and scooby snack . Sorry

Comment: I know, I started this late last night after a full day of working. I'll be sure to fix those!

Comment: Lol! Sorry about that. Be sure to upload it on code review for others to see too later on

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    string userName;
    //int choice1;
    //int choice2;
    //int choice3;
    int event1;
    int event2;
    int event3;
    int event4;
    int event5;

    int gameOver = 0;

    cout << "What is your name, traveler?" << endl;
    cin >> userName;

    cout << "\nWelcome, " << userName << "." << endl;
    cout << "I'm going to ask you a series of questions." << endl;
    cout << "To cotinue your adventure, answer them by typing" << endl;
    cout << "either 1, 2, or 3." << endl;

    cout << "\nYou're walking down a long dirt road. You hear footsteps behind you," << endl;
    cout << "but you're too afraid to look right now. A fork in the road lies infront of you." << endl;

    cout << "\nWhat do you do?" << endl;
    cout << "1 - Turn left, and run down the hill." << endl;
    cout << "2 - Turn right, and run towards the abandoned house in the distance." << endl;
    cout << "3 - Gain the courage to turn around and face whatever is behind you." << endl;
    cin >> event1;
    if(event1 == 1)
    {
        cout << "Unfortunatley, you trip over a branch, and fall to your death.\n" << endl;
        gameOver = 1;
    }
    else if(event1 == 2)
    {
        cout << "You run towards the house, and escape the creature following you." << endl;
    }
    else if(event1 == 3)
    {
        cout << "You turn around, but before you can make out the features of the creature behind you, it kills you.\n" << endl;
        gameOver = 1;
    }   

    if (!gameOver)
    {
        cout << "As you get closer to the house, you notice a light is on upstairs." << endl;
        cout << "A small path leads to the back of the house.\n" << endl;
        cout << "What do you do?" << endl;
        cout << "1 - Knock on the door, and hope whoever is inside won't kill you." << endl;
        cout << "2 - Enter the hoouse unanounced, and sneak upstairs." << endl;
        cout << "3 - Follow the path to the back of the house." << endl;
        cin >> event2;
        if(event2 == 1)
        {
            cout << "A drunk, confused man answers the door, shotgun in hand." << endl;
            cout << "You raise your hands in defense, but before you can explain yourself, he shoots." << endl;
            gameOver = 1;
        }
        else if(event2 == 2)
        {
            cout << "You slowly open the door, and quietly sneak upstairs." << endl;
        }
        else if(event2 == 3)
        {
            cout << "You sneak around the house, and become face to face with a vicious gaurd dog." << endl;
            cout << "Before you can give it a Scooby-Snac, it bits your throat, and kills you." << endl;
            gameOver = 1;
        }

        if (!gameOver)
        {
            cout << "You see three doorways, one leads to a dimly lit room, the second to a brightly lit room, and the third to a pitch black room." << endl;
            cout << "\nWhat do you do?" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically just store whether the game is over or not in `gameOver`. Instead of calling `gameOver()`, just set this new `gameOver` variable to `1` (which means `true`). Then, later, you can check whether the game is over or not and skip everything else if it is.

Comment: Would I use a `break` statement to skip the other outputs?

Comment: @furiousjelly no. Use exit statement